# Speed up Word failure when missing network .dot template

Tags: windows, networking, microsoft-word, templates

We have a partner which is sending us documents with references to a template on their own LAN, and thus cannot be loaded when we receive them.  When we receive them, it can take over a minute for the file to load due to the 'missing' .dot file.  Unfortunately, they are refusing to remove the reference, or move the .dot file reference to the c: drive, which would fail much quicker.  As far as I know, since the reference is on a server which does not exist, Windows must be doing some exhaustive search for that server and it's taking a long time.

Aside from changing the local host file, which would be a messy hack, is there any other way to speed up the failure, in Word or Windows?

Comment: What version of Word?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a command line or shortcut to start Word without add-ins or templates. Here is a [reference](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/210565) to the Microsoft Support article.

> For example, if you want to start Word and prevent the loading of add-ins and global templates, type the following in the Open box, including the quotation marks:
>    **"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office\Winword.exe" /a**

This should help you avoid the template issue.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled accross this when we had also this problem with external Word-Documents which referenced Templates from foreign Servers.

I finally found a registry setting for Word, which controls a timeout for loading remote templates:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Word\Options]
"UseTimeoutForAttachedTemplateLoad"=dword:00000001
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the documents have any pictures in them ?, if it is just text you could just ask them to send it in an RTF instead, as I don't think this stores that sort of info in it.